# JavaScript quotes in onclick

Tags: javascript, dom-events, shadowbox

I am trying to add an `onclick` code to some JavaScript for some shadowbox.

Here is the code:

```
Shadowbox.open({
        content:    'my.php',
        player:     "iframe",
        title:      '<div><a href="#" rel="shadowbox" onclick="Shadowbox.open({ content: \'page2.php\', width: 460, height: 270, player:\'iframe\' }); return false;"></a></div>',
        height:     800,
        width:      1024,

    });
```

Latest I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#mydiv").on("click", "#sb-title", function(){

     Shadowbox.open({
    content: 'somepage.php', 
    width: 460, 
    height: 270, 
    player:'iframe'     
    });
    
    });

});
```

...then...

```
Shadowbox.open({
content:    'someotherpage.php',
player:     "iframe",
title:      '<div><a id="mydiv" href="#">Clickme</a></div>',
height:     800,
width:      1024,

});
```

The above is doing nothing.

For some reason the `onclick` is not happening ... is this a syntax issue with the quotes?

How can I fix this?

Comment: They certainly look a little weird, try to simplify the "title" part (leave only empty div there for example) and try if it works, then add other parts to see whats wrong, easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add just normal text as a title (do not add `onclick`).

Then you may add some script to track clicks:

```
$("body").on("click", "#sb-title", function(){
    Shadowbox.open({
        content: 'page2.php', 
        width: 460, 
        height: 270, 
        player:'iframe' }
})
```

**EDIT**
From your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //you may try '#sb-wrapper' instead of 'body'
    $("body").on("click", "#sb-title", function(){

         Shadowbox.open({
            content: 'somepage.php', 
            width: 460, 
            height: 270, 
            player:'iframe'     
         });

    });

});
```

...then...

```
Shadowbox.open({
    content:    'someotherpage.php',
    player:     "iframe",
    title:      'Clickme',
    height:     800,
    width:      1024,

});
```

Comment: Tried the above but no luck...I've edited the question and added the latest code I'm trying ... from your code.

Comment: Still no luck :( I've even tried adding an alert to it..but no alert showing

Comment: Is your jQuery quite recent? Does it support `.on()`?